# Как отправить данные с динамической формы?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, formdata

Есть некая форма типа:

```
<form>
 <span id='3'>
  <input type="text" name="name" class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
  <input type="text" name="desc" class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
  <input type="text" name="note" class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
<span id='8'>
  <input type="text" name="name" class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
  <input type="text" name="desc" class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
  <input type="text" name="note" class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
...
...
...
<span id='56'>
  <input type="text" name="name" class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
  <input type="text" name="desc" class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
  <input type="text" name="note" class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
</form>
```

Т.е. непонятно количество групп полей. Как ajax'ом передать на сервер все введенные данные и как потом на сервере их обработать?
Догадываюсь, что как-то можно использовать **FormData()** в клиентской части и на сервере обойти полученное с помощью **foreach**. Но не понимаю, как именно это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
 <span id='3'>
   <input type="text" name=name[] class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
   <input type="text" name=desc[] class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
   <input type="text" name=note[] class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
 <span id='3'>
   <input type="text" name=name[] class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
   <input type="text" name=desc[] class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
   <input type="text" name=note[] class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
 <span id='3'>
   <input type="text" name=name[] class='name' placeholder="Название" /> 
   <input type="text" name=desc[] class='desc' placeholder="Описание" />
   <input type="text" name=note[] class='notr' placeholder="Примечание" />
 </span>
</form>
```

принимаешь в php файле как $_POST['name'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['note'] и перебираешь каждого как массив